# get value of list item with click event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have two components
which displaying
each element of  `const elementObjects = [{id: 1, Element: "Orange", Weight: 55}, {id:2, Element: "Banana", Mass: 20}];` 
in an unorderd list
I want to log the value of a list item to the console if `clicked`

`return <li onClick={(e)=> console.log(e.target.value)}>{props.value}</li>;`

when clicked the eventHandler return `0` instead of `Orange`
how can I get the desired behavior ?

```
function ListItem(props) {
    // --> displays the data / is reusable
  return <li onClick={(e)=> console.log(e.target.value)}>{props.value}</li>;
}

function ChooseElements() {

  const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) =>
  
    <ListItem key={object.id.toString()} value={object.Element} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <ChooseElements />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Try `props.value` (the value of the `value` prop) instead of `e.target.value` (the value of the `value` attribute of the `li` HTML element, which is unlikely to be anything interesting, since you haven't set it to anything interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `e.target`. Your value is coming from your props. Your `ListItem` should look like this to log the value once clicked:

```js
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li onClick={() => console.log(props.value)}>{props.value}</li>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go. use props.value for onClick

```js
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li onClick={()=> console.log(props.value)}>{props.value}</li>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use value from props instead of event target?

Something like this:

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li onClick={() => console.log(props.value)}>{props.value}</li>;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

li elements don't specifically have e.target.value
So you'll have to console.log props.value

```
function ListItem(props) {
    // --> displays the data / is reusable
  return <li onClick={(e)=> console.log(props.value)}>{props.value}</li>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the props.value to the onClick event handler and there won't be a need for e.target.value.